# Is it possible to pull column descriptions from BigQuery metadata

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the column descriptions from the BigQuery metadata but I can't seem to find it, I've tried using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but it isn't contained in here, does anyone know where it is please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have access to all the columns metadata by querying the `COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS` table:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourdataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
```

Doc reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#column_field_paths_view)

You get information about column names and types within all your dataset.